# How do I find sum of a number range using multiple threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

The system is supposed to calculate the sum of a number range in x amount of threads, where the number range and x number of threads are entered by the user.

Example if the range is 1-4 that is to be calculated in 2 threads:

```
Thread 1: 1 + 2 = 3
Thread 2: 3 + 4 = 7

Total = 10
```

The MyThread class is just an example I wrote for me to better understand how threads works and not the actual attempt of a solution.

MyThread Class:

```
class MyThread implements Runnable {
    private String name;

    MyThread(String thread) {
        name = thread;
        System.out.println("Start: " + name);
        try { Thread.sleep(500); } catch (Exception e) { System.out.println(e); }
    }

    //countdown from 5 to 1 for each thread
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i=5; i>0; i--){
            System.out.println(name + ": " + i);
            try { Thread.sleep(500); } catch (Exception e) { System.out.println(e); }
        }
        System.out.println(name + " Exiting");
    }
}
```

Main Class:

```
public class SimpleThreadExample {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread t = new Thread();

        //get number of threads from user
        System.out.print("Enter the number of threads: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number = input.nextInt();

        //create the threads
        for (int i=1; i<=number; i++) {
            t = new Thread(new MyThread("Thread " + i));
            t.start();
        }

        t.join();
        System.out.println("End");
    }
}
```

I am currently at a loss as to how I should display and add the numbers together in different threads. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi OJ, you could divide the range by the number of threads and pass each subrange to a thread. You can pass the subrange using the MyThread constructor. In the run method, you can do the summing and store the result in a result field also in the MyThread class. Then you call join on each thread to wait for them to "die", after they "die" you can read the results from each one and sum.

Comment: I'll definitely try it out, this seems like a great solution

Comment: Read about [Java BlockingQueue](https://www.journaldev.com/1034/java-blockingqueue-example)

Answer (score 5):

A simple Java-8 way would be to use parallel streams.

```
int[] numbers = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

int sum = Arrays.stream (numbers).parallel()
                        .sum ();
```

If you need to do it by creating Threads manually. You can do something around the lines of below.

```
    CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch (2);

    SummationTask task1 = new SummationTask (countDownLatch,Arrays.copyOfRange (numbers, 0, numbers.length / 2));
    SummationTask task2 = new SummationTask (countDownLatch,Arrays.copyOfRange (numbers, (numbers.length / 2), numbers.length));
    Thread thread = new Thread (task1);
    Thread thread2 = new Thread (task2);
    thread.start ();
    thread2.start ();
    try {
        countDownLatch.await ();
        int totalSum = task1.sum + task2.sum;
        System.out.println ("sum => " + totalSum);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace ();
    }
```

In SummationTask, add the split array elements.

```
class SummationTask implements Runnable {

    CountDownLatch countDownLatch;
    int[] arr;
    int sum;

    public SummationTask(CountDownLatch countDownLatch, int[] arr) {
        this.countDownLatch = countDownLatch;
        this.arr = arr;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int sum = Arrays.stream (arr)
                .sum ();
        this.sum = sum;
        countDownLatch.countDown ();
    }
}
```

**PS: Above solution creates 2 threads, you can improve upon this by using ThreadPool of the desired size (split array in intervals) and `Callable` and `Future`. You can get rid of CountDownLatch if you use Future**

Comment: Is it possible to create the threads dynamically instead of manually with this example? Because it seems impossible to split the array of numbers into subranges without entering the formula manually.

Comment: is it some kind of academic assignment? or a business problem? If it's a business problem I highly recommend you use a parallel stream.

Comment: The approach described in the answer uses hard-coded number of threads. Also, about using `parallel`: much appropriate for the task would be `IntStream.rangeClosed(start, end).parallel().sum()`

Comment: @Zgurskyi number of thread is hardcoded that I know and is being mentioned in the answer also.

Comment: @GovindaSakhare Then your answer is irrelevant, because it's explicitly mentioned, that threads should be entered dynamically. Also, in your suggestion with Arrays.stream, you are not actually controlling number of threads to be used.

Comment: @Zgurski If you want You can edit and improve the answer. Thanks for the inputs

Comment: @Zgurskyi Okay I will update it by going through it. Thanks again.

Comment: @GovindaSakhare it's actually just an academic assignment